# SQL Parameters won't apply to command

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql

Im trying to use the sql parameters to avoid sql injection in my query however the parameters don't seem to apply to the command.

```
public static IList<Call> GetCallsFilter(string startdate, string enddate,List<String>ContextName, List<String>ValueName, List<String>TypeName)
{

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAMConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {

        connection.Open();

        startdate += " 00:00:00";
        enddate += " 23:59:59";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", connection))
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT dbo.Calls.CallID, dbo.Connections.Connectionname,dbo.Calls.ConnectionID, dbo.Calls.ParentID, dbo.Calls.StartTime, dbo.Calls.EndTime, REPLACE(dbo.Calls.Querytime, ',', '.') AS Querytijd, dbo.Calls.Template, dbo.Calls.Profilecall, dbo.Calls.Objectcall, dbo.Calls.Method, dbo.Calls.Error, dbo.Calls.Category, dbo.Calls.Uur, dbo.Calls.DayOfMonth, dbo.Repositorys.RepositoryName,dbo.Calls.ResultLink, REPLACE(MAX(Querytime) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(yyyy, dbo.Calls.StartTime), DATEPART(M, dbo.Calls.StartTime), dbo.Calls.DayOfMonth, dbo.Calls.Uur, DATEPART(MINUTE, dbo.Calls.StartTime)), ',', '.') AS MaxQueryTime FROM dbo.Calls INNER JOIN dbo.Connections ON dbo.Calls.ConnectionID = dbo.Connections.ConnectionID INNER JOIN dbo.Repositorys ON dbo.Connections.RepositoryID = dbo.Repositorys.RepositoryID where StartTime BETWEEN '" + startdate + "' AND '" + enddate + "'";
            if (ContextName != null && ValueName != null)
            {


                for (int i = 0; i < ContextName.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ContextName[i].ToString() != "Filter")
                    {
                        if (TypeName[i].ToString() == "LIKE")
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText += " AND exists (Select * from dbo.Context where CallID = dbo.Calls.CallID and Name=@Name and Value like @Value)";
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", ContextName[i].ToString()));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Value", ValueName[i].ToString()));




                        }
                        else if (TypeName[i].ToString() == "=")
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText += " AND exists (Select * from dbo.Context where CallID = dbo.Calls.CallID and Name='" + Regex.Escape(ContextName[i].ToString()) + "' and Value = '" + Regex.Escape(ValueName[i].ToString()) + "')";

                        }
                        else if (TypeName[i].ToString() == "NOT LIKE")
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText += " AND exists (Select * from dbo.Context where CallID = dbo.Calls.CallID and Name='" + Regex.Escape(ContextName[i].ToString()) + "' and Value NOT like '%" + Regex.Escape(ValueName[i].ToString()) + "%')";
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {


                CallData = new List<Call>();

                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);

                foreach (DataRow rij in table.Rows)
                {
                    CallData.Add(new Call() { CallID = Int64.Parse(rij[0].ToString()), Connectionname = rij[1].ToString(), ConnectionID = rij[2].ToString(), ParentID = rij[3].ToString(), StartTime = ((DateTime)rij[4]).ToString("d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"), EndTime = ((DateTime)rij[5]).ToString("d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"), Querytime = rij[6].ToString(), Template = rij[7].ToString(), Profile = rij[8].ToString(), Object = rij[9].ToString(), Method = rij[10].ToString(), Error = rij[11].ToString(), Category = rij[12].ToString(), Uur = rij[13].ToString(), DayOfMonth = rij[14].ToString(), Repository = rij[15].ToString(), Datum = rij[4].ToString(), ResultLink = rij[16].ToString(), MaxQuerytime = rij[17].ToString() });

                }

            }

        }




}

    return CallData;

}
```

Im currently just trying it out in the IF LIKE function but won't work atm.

Comment: Just trying to understand, what are corresponding fields for `startdate` and `enddate`? And why do you use `+=` for them instead of `=`?

Comment: can you try to see the final result of your command text? And also if you are saying "it is not working" how do you know it? Do you get error message or your query gets nothing?

Comment: My datatable is empty however if i look in the debugger the command has the parameters i can see the values of it. But when it fills the table it is empty.Also before i tried to use parameters i just added the values to the command and that worked fine.

Comment: I think `if (ContextName != null && ValueName != null)` returns false so your cmd.CommandText is not built.

Comment: Could you please use verbatim strings instead of long single line string?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IList<Call> GetCallsFilter(string startdate, string enddate,List<String>ContextName, List<String>ValueName, List<String>TypeName)
{

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAMConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {

        connection.Open();

        startdate += " 00:00:00";
        enddate += " 23:59:59";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", connection))
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.CallID, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Connections.Connectionname, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.ConnectionID, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.ParentID, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.StartTime, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.EndTime, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " REPLACE(dbo.Calls.Querytime, ',', '.') ";
                cmd.CommandText += " AS ";
                cmd.CommandText += " Querytijd, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.Template, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.Profilecall, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.Objectcall, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.Method, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.Error, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.Category, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.Uur, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.DayOfMonth, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Repositorys.RepositoryName, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.ResultLink, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " REPLACE(MAX(Querytime) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(yyyy, dbo.Calls.StartTime), ";
                cmd.CommandText += " DATEPART(M, dbo.Calls.StartTime), ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.DayOfMonth, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.Uur, ";
                cmd.CommandText += " DATEPART(MINUTE, dbo.Calls.StartTime)), ',', '.') ";
                cmd.CommandText += " AS MaxQueryTime FROM dbo.Calls ";
                cmd.CommandText += " INNER JOIN dbo.Connections ON ";
                cmd.CommandText += " dbo.Calls.ConnectionID = dbo.Connections.ConnectionID ";
                cmd.CommandText += " INNER JOIN dbo.Repositorys ON dbo.Connections.RepositoryID = dbo.Repositorys.RepositoryID ";
                cmd.CommandText += " where StartTime BETWEEN @stardate AND @enddate ";


                if (ContextName != null && ValueName != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ContextName.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (ContextName[i].ToString() != "Filter")
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText += " AND exists ";
                            cmd.CommandText += "(Select * from dbo.Context ";
                            cmd.CommandText += " where CallID = dbo.Calls.CallID and Name=@Name and Value ";
                            cmd.CommandText += TypeName[i].ToString();
                            cmd.CommandText += " @Value)";

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Context", ContextName[i].ToString());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", ValueName[i].ToString());
                        }
                    }

                }

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startdate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", enddate);

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {

                CallData = new List<Call>();

                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);

                foreach (DataRow rij in table.Rows)
                {
                    CallData.Add(new Call() { CallID = Int64.Parse(rij[0].ToString()), Connectionname = rij[1].ToString(), ConnectionID = rij[2].ToString(), ParentID = rij[3].ToString(), StartTime = ((DateTime)rij[4]).ToString("d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"), EndTime = ((DateTime)rij[5]).ToString("d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"), Querytime = rij[6].ToString(), Template = rij[7].ToString(), Profile = rij[8].ToString(), Object = rij[9].ToString(), Method = rij[10].ToString(), Error = rij[11].ToString(), Category = rij[12].ToString(), Uur = rij[13].ToString(), DayOfMonth = rij[14].ToString(), Repository = rij[15].ToString(), Datum = rij[4].ToString(), ResultLink = rij[16].ToString(), MaxQuerytime = rij[17].ToString() });

                }

           }
      }
 }

     return CallData;

}
```

Comment: Still aint getting results. By the looks of it the parameters doesn't seem to apply to the command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "@" to the parameter name.

```
new SqlParameter("@Name", ContextName[i].ToString())
new SqlParameter("@Value", ValueName[i].ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ContextName[i].ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", ValueName[i].ToString());
```